# Show that a set is open in $(C[0,1], d_\infty)$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X = C[0,1]$ and $d_\infty(x,y) = \max_{t\in [0,1]} \lvert x(t) - y(t) \rvert$ be a metric on $X$. Let $A = \{x \in X: \lvert x(t) \rvert < 1, t\in [0,1]\}$. Is $A$ open in $(X,d_\infty)$?

Define openness as all points in the set are interior points. I guess that the statement is true. I have tried to show that an arbitrary point in $A$ is an interior point, and separately to show that $A^c$ is closed. In the first case I want to show that for some $x\in A$ and a ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ we have $y \in B(x, \epsilon) \implies \lvert y(t) \rvert < 1$. Without the details, I arrive at $$d_\infty(x,y) < \epsilon \implies \dots \implies \lvert x(t)\rvert - \epsilon < \lvert y(t) \rvert < \lvert x(t) \rvert + \epsilon.$$ Because $x\in A$, then $\lvert y(t) \rvert < 1 + \epsilon$. Now this is the problem, how can I conclude that $\lvert y(t) \rvert < 1$?
Similarly, in the latter method I instead try to show that all limit points of $A^c$ are contained, i.e. if $x$ is a limit point then $\lvert x(t) \rvert \geq 1$. This (without details) ultimately leads to the inequality $ 1 - \epsilon < \lvert x(t) \rvert < 1+ \epsilon$, which is of course the same as before. Is these attempts lost causes, or am I doing something wrong? Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The essential point you need is that $[0,1]$ is compact so $x\in C([0,1])$ takes its maximal and minimal values. This implies that if $|x(t)|<1$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ then there is in fact $r<1$ so that $|x(t)|\leq r<1$ for all $t$ and you may then proceed with your proof.

Comment: That is clever. I think I see how this will solve my issues, but I will give it a try first.

Comment: Just finished the proof, thanks!